# Get elements from a list by their type of struct in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a `params` map and want to get the list of values who's "type" is `%Plug.Upload{}`. How do I check for the type in Elixir?

Answer (score 4):

You can pattern match on structs just as you can on maps, so you can use `Enum.filter` and `Kernel.match?`:

```
params
|> Enum.filter(&match?(%Plug.Upload{}, &1))
```

Answer (score 0):

params is a map, so Enum.filter gets key/value pairs, and the value is what will be a Plug.Upload, so:

```
params |> Enum.filter(fn({k, v}) -> match?(%Plug.Upload{}, v) end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern `%Plug.Upload{}` with `for` as `for` skips all the items that do not match the passed pattern.

This will return a list of all the files present in the values of the Map `params`:

```
for {_, %Plug.Upload{} = file} <- params, do: file
```

If you just want to do something with the file, you can pass a block to `do`:

```
for {_, %Plug.Upload{} = file} <- params do
  IO.inspect file
end
```

Change `_` to a variable name if you also want to access the file's name as present in the form that was submitted.